# a function that looks for "string" existing in a file path

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm used to regex in Ruby, so i'm a lisp noob.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c t")
        (lambda()
          (interactive)
          (if string-match-p file-name-directory "spec"
            (shell-command (concat "rspec " (file-name-directory (buffer-file-name))))
            )
          )
        )
```

Basically i want to only run this line (or an else for 'test')  if the `file-name-directory` has the word `spec` in it.

Example: `/user/me/app/spec/test.rb`

How does one get the if statement to work?

so far i get: `Symbol's value as variable is void: string-match-p` in the mini buffer. Thanks.

Comment: You are missing a basic understanding of Lisp.  You will do yourself a favor by taking a look at this fine manual, which is embedded in Emacs: `An Introduction to Programming in Emacs Lisp`.  You get to it using `C-h i` and then choosing `Emacs Lisp Intro`.  Start at the beginning.  You will learn how to apply a function, such as `string-match-p`, to its arguments -- and much more that is basic.

Comment: I didn't have that Intro to Lisp in my Emacs 24, but the wiki said to put this in Scratch buffer `(info "(eintr) Top")` and then `C+j` to evaluate it.

Comment: If you really do not have it as part of your Emacs build, you can probably find it online by googling for it.  It's well worth checking out.  Enjoy.

Comment: The Lisp intro is [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want this to act on the current buffer, if so, try this:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c t")
        (lambda()
          (interactive)
          (let* ((full-name (buffer-file-name))
                 (path (when full-name
                   (file-name-directory full-name))))
            (when (and path (string-match "spec" path))
              (shell-command (concat "rspec " path))))))
```

Comment: `string-match-p` is better than `string-match`, if you do not need to use the `match-data`.

Comment: @Drew you are correct, i don't want to use that data. I'm going to give the answer a spin now.

Comment: This worked. I'm assuming if i wanted to run 'test' i can just change 'spec' to 'test' in another when . Thanks!

Comment: Yes, changing the string-match will do it; glad this helped